# Block previous days from being display in DatePicker

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I've a problem where I want to block the previous date from being display in `DatePicker` tool of Toolkit or you can say that I want to apply some limit to the dates.

***For example:***

- If today's date is 15/7/2013 then by clicking on `DatePicker` control it's should not display the dates previous to 15/7/2013.
- Its should show the next 30 days but not beyond that.

I'll be thankful to all who suggest their answers and opinion.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. However, you can download the source and modify it to add your requirements. The source code is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yeah, that's the last option then, is their no other way?

Comment: No, the control doesn't support what you need so you have to modify it.

Comment: Ok, I did it, thanks a lot, actually I was aware of this thing that we have to change the source code but want to know whether there is some other way or not. Please post your suggestion as your answer so that I can mark it as correct which will be helpful for others. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. However, you can download the source and modify it to add your requirements. The source code is pretty straightforward.